How did they make this graph on Wikipedia?
I was reading this Wikipedia's "Cauchy's integral formula" entry and found this image:

I was wondering, how did they make this graph?
At first I thought this was a real variable and made the following graph (in R):
$$ g(z) = \frac{z^2}{z^2 + 2z + 2} $$


g <- function(z) {
    z^2 / (z^2 + 2*z + 2)
}

z <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 1000)

g_values <- g(z)

df <- data.frame(z = z, g_values = g_values)
ggplot(df, aes(x = z, y = g_values)) +
    geom_line(color = "blue") +
    labs(title = "Plot of g(z) = z^2 / (z^2 + 2z + 2)",
         x = "z",
         y = "g(z)") +
    theme_minimal()


After re-reading this, I realized that the variable in this function is actually a complex variable!  I am not very familiar with complex variables and tried to work through some of the manipulations.
I first defined:
$$
z = x + iy
$$
I then started by substituting $ z = x + iy $ into the function:
$$
g(z) = \frac{(x + iy)^2}{(x + iy)^2 + 2(x + iy) + 2}
$$
First, expand $ (x + iy)^2 $:
$$
(x + iy)^2 = x^2 + 2ixy - y^2
$$
Thus:
$$
g(z) = \frac{x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy}{(x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy) + 2(x + iy) + 2}
$$
Then  the denominator:
$$
(x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy) + 2(x + iy) + 2 = (x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2) + i(2xy + 2y)
$$
Thus, the denominator is:
$$
(x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2) + i(2xy + 2y)
$$
So, $ g(z) $ can be written as:
$$
g(z) = \frac{(x^2 - y^2) + 2ixy}{(x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2) + i(2xy + 2y)}
$$
This part was a bit confusing to me. I know I need to separate $ g(z) $ into its real and imaginary parts. After doing some more reading, it seems this can be done by multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by the conjugate of the denominator (this cancels out the imaginary part). The conjugate of the denominator $ D(z) = (x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2) + i(2xy + 2y) $ is:
$$
\overline{D(z)} = (x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2) - i(2xy + 2y)
$$
Multiply both the numerator and denominator by $ \overline{D(z)} $:
$$
g(z) = \frac{(x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy) \cdot [(x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2) - i(2xy + 2y)]}{[(x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2) + i(2xy + 2y)] \cdot [(x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2) - i(2xy + 2y)]}
$$
The denominator becomes:
$$
\text{Denominator} = (x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2)^2 + (2xy + 2y)^2
$$
Expanding the numerator:
$$
\text{Numerator} = \left[(x^2 - y^2)(x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2) + (2ixy)(x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 2)\right] - \left[(x^2 - y^2)(2xy + 2y) + (2ixy)(2xy + 2y)\right]i
$$
After simplification, it seems that we can isolate the real part $ \text{Re}(g(z)) $ and the imaginary part $ \text{Im}(g(z)) $:
$$
\text{Re}(g(z)) = \frac{\text{Real part of the Numerator}}{\text{Denominator}}
$$
$$
\text{Im}(g(z)) = \frac{\text{Imaginary part of the Numerator}}{\text{Denominator}}
$$
Again, I tried to plot this real part in R (while keeping the same color scale):
library(plotly)

x_vals <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
y_vals <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)

x <- rep(x_vals, each = length(y_vals))
y <- rep(y_vals, times = length(x_vals))

# Define the numerator and denominator
num_real <- x^2 - y^2  # Real part of the numerator
num_imag <- 2 * x * y  # Imaginary part of the numerator

denom_real <- (x^2 - y^2 + 2 * x + 2)  # Real part 
denom_imag <- (2 * x * y + 2 * y)  # Imaginary part

real_part <- (num_real * denom_real + num_imag * denom_imag) / 
    (denom_real^2 + denom_imag^2)

z_matrix <- matrix(real_part, nrow = length(x_vals), ncol = length(y_vals))

plot_ly(x = ~x_vals, y = ~y_vals, z = ~z_matrix) %>%
    add_surface(colorscale = list(
        c(0, 'rgb(255,182,193)'),  # Light pink
        c(1, 'rgb(128,0,128)')     # Purple
    )) %>%
    layout(scene = list(
        xaxis = list(title = "Re(z)"),
        yaxis = list(title = "Im(z)"),
        zaxis = list(title = "Real Part of f(z)")
    ),
    title = "3D Plot of the Real Part of f(z)")


Is my understanding of the math correct?
Thanks!
PS: Taking inspiration from Heropup's code, I re-wrote the R function:
library(plotly)

f <- function(x, y) {
    z <- complex(real = x, imaginary = y)
    Re((z^2) / (z^2 + 2*z + 2))
}

# grid
x <- y <- seq(-4, 4, length.out = 200)
grid <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)

z <- outer(x, y, Vectorize(f))

# Main plot
p <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z) %>%
    add_surface(
        colorscale = list(
            c(0, "rgb(255,182,193)"),  # Light pink
            c(1, "rgb(128,0,128)")     # Purple
        ),
        lighting = list(ambient = 0.6, diffuse = 0.5, specular = 0.1),
        contours = list(
            z = list(
                show = TRUE,
                usecolormap = TRUE,
                highlightcolor = "#ffffff",
                project = list(z = TRUE)
            )
        )
    )

for (i in seq(-4, 4, length.out = 13)) {
    p <- p %>% add_mesh(
        x = x,
        y = rep(i, length(x)),
        z = outer(x, rep(i, length(x)), Vectorize(f)),
        opacity = 0.2,
        color = I("white"),
        hoverinfo = "none"
    )
    p <- p %>% add_mesh(
        x = rep(i, length(y)),
        y = y,
        z = outer(rep(i, length(y)), y, Vectorize(f)),
        opacity = 0.2,
        color = I("white"),
        hoverinfo = "none"
    )
}

t <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 100)

# Curve 1: 2*exp(i*t)
curve1 <- data.frame(
    x = 2 * cos(t),
    y = 2 * sin(t),
    z = f(2 * cos(t), 2 * sin(t))
)

# Curve 2: exp(i*t)/2 - 1 + i
curve2 <- data.frame(
    x = 0.5 * cos(t) - 1,
    y = 0.5 * sin(t) + 1,
    z = f(0.5 * cos(t) - 1, 0.5 * sin(t) + 1)
)

# Curve 3: exp(i*t)/2 - 1 - i
curve3 <- data.frame(
    x = 0.5 * cos(t) - 1,
    y = 0.5 * sin(t) - 1,
    z = f(0.5 * cos(t) - 1, 0.5 * sin(t) - 1)
)

p <- p %>%
    add_trace(data = curve1, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'black', width = 4), name = 'Curve 1') %>%
    add_trace(data = curve2, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'red', width = 4), name = 'Curve 2') %>%
    add_trace(data = curve3, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'blue', width = 4), name = 'Curve 3')

p <- p %>% layout(
    scene = list(
        aspectmode = "manual",
        aspectratio = list(x = 1, y = 1, z = 0.65),
        xaxis = list(range = c(-4, 4), title = "Re(z)"),
        yaxis = list(range = c(-4, 4), title = "Im(z)"),
        zaxis = list(range = c(-4, 4), title = "Re(f(z))")
    )
)

p



The original graphic, according to the image metadata, was created in MuPad, which is now only available as part of Matlab.
In Mathematica, I was able to create a reasonable facsimile:
Show[
  Plot3D[Re[#^2/(#^2 + 2 # + 2)] &[x + I y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
   PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.3], 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .65}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
   Lighting -> "Neutral", ClippingStyle -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[0.95, 0.6, 1], Hue[0.65, 0.35, 1]}, #3] &)], 
  Plot3D[Re[#^2/(#^2 + 2 # + 2)] &[x + I  y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshShading -> {None}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[White, Thickness[Medium], Opacity[0.2]], 
   Mesh -> 13, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 8, ClippingStyle -> None], 
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[
   {Re[#], Im[#], Re[#^2/(#^2 + 2 # + 2)]} & /@ {2 Exp[I t], 
    Exp[I t]/2 - 1 + I, Exp[I t]/2 - 1 - I}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive /@ {{Black, Thick}, {Red, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}}]
  ]

The output, after rotating the viewpoint, looks like this:

Again, it's not perfect, but it preserves the salient features of the original plot, with the exception of the level curves projected onto the plane $z = -4$ below.  These are easy to include but I chose not to do so, because they are barely visible in the original plot, and you can already see the structure in the 3D plot itself.
One thing I struggled with (and this is probably more appropriate for Mathematica.SE) is how to adjust the plot's specular lighting in conjunction with a color gradient.  I was unsuccessful, which is why the plot has diffuse lighting.

Regarding the mathematics of what is being plotted, if you use Mathematica to perform the symbolic algebra,
Factor[Together[Most[ComplexExpand[#^2/(#^2 + 2 # + 2) &[x + I y]]]]]

we get, after additional manual factoring,
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2(x+1)^2 + (x+y^2)^2 + 2(x^2-1)y^2}{((x+1)^2+(y-1)^2)((x+1)^2+(y+1)^2)}.$$
If you plot this function as $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, you will get the desired figure.  A contour plot is illustrated below; note the direction of the axes.

And here is an animation of the plot, without the circular contours:


I don't know what tools they used. The standard is mostly Mathematica today
The complex function
g[z_] :=  (z^2)/((z - 1 - I) (z - 1 + I))  

The 3D plot of the real part with a color indicator of the complex phase
RealSurface=
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Re[g[x + I y]]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, PlotRange -> {All, All, {-4, 4}}, 
 Mesh -> {8, 8},  
 MeshStyle -> Yellow, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8], 
ColorFunction -> ( 
     Function[{x, y, u, v}, Hue[ (Arg[x + I y] + \[Pi])/2 \[Pi]]]),
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, Re z},  
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{(Hue[#] &), {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}}]]

and a circle of radius 2 around the origin,  projection to the surface
Contour =
ParametricPlot3D[{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t], Re[g[2 E^(I t)]]}, 
 {t, 0,  2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Black ]

 Show[{RealSurface,Contour}]



@ Roland: thank you! Was the function I plotted correct?
